# SQL : Iterate through rows and update set of rows that have same primary key

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table called ***Provider_Compliances***
 (ProviderNum,
 ProviderLocation,
 HistorySequence,
 ProviderEffectiveDate,
 PeriodBeginDate,
 PeriodEndDate,
 IsCompliant)

### Example of data :

```
ProviderNum |ProviderLocatin  |HistorySequence|ProviderEffectiveDate|PeriodBeginDate|PeriodEndDate|IsCompliant
         1  |              1  |          2  |   2012-01-01        |  2010-01-03   | 2012-01-01  | No
         2  |              2  |          2  |   2012-01-01        |  2012-01-02   | 9999-12-31  | Yes
```

The primary key for the Provider_Compliances Table is (ProviderNumber,HistorySequence, ProviderLocation, ProviderEffectiveDate).

I am trying to add a new columns (ComplianceNumber) and then change the primary key of the Provider_Compliances Table to composite key (ComplianceNumber, HistorySequence).

I don't want to lose any preexisting data.

So, I thought of doing it this way :

//1st, add the new column(ComplianceNumber) with default value 0

```
ALTER TABLE Provider_Compliances ADD ComplianceNumber DECIMAL(10) DEFAULT 0
```

//2nd, update all existing rows

```
UPDATE Provider_Compliances SET ComplianceNumber = (NEXT VALUE FOR Provider_Compliances_Sequence)
```

//3rd, modify the primary key

```
ALTER TABLE Provider_Compliances DROP PRIMARY KEY
ALTER TABLE Provider_Compliances ADD PRIMARY KEY(ComplianceNumber, HistorySequence)
```

The problem with step 2 is that it will set every row to a new ComplianceNumber.
I want every row that has the same ProviderNumber + ProviderLocation + ProviderEffectiveDate to be granted the same ComplianceNumber.

Comment: If you want to have multiple rows with the same ComplianceNumber, it can't be a primary key.

Comment: That is true, @DuncanHowe. I've made a mistake. I actually wanted to use a new composite primary key made of (ComplianceNumber, ProviderLocation)

Comment: Based on your example data, you are still going to end up with duplicate primary keys by using ComplianceNumber and ProviderLocation. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: oooh. I forgot to include they column historysequence which differentaites every row from each other.

Comment: That doesn't help...both rows have the same historysequence. Assuming you have mixed the ProviderLocation and HistorySequence fields up you want to look at a ranking function to generate the ComplianceNumber - whether you do this via some form of temporary table or in one hit, that is up to you, but I am not optimistic about your success. I still think you will end up with duplicates.

Comment: The historysequence column is used to differentiate between rows. It is used for historical purposes. Whenever a change is made, instead of deleting the row, a new one with higher historysequence is inserted and at any time, only one current active row is available (by selecting the record with the max history sequence)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16670/discussion-between-duncan-howe-and-attilah)

Comment: ok, can you please give me 15 min so I can get to a suitable computer ? . network filters are stopping me from opening the chat link u sent. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to do this with a SQL script as follows

1. Create a temp table with records group by ProviderNumber +
   ProviderLocation + ProviderEffectiveDate including new column
2. Loop through temp table and update the new column (with incremental number - or as you needed)
3. Join this table with original one & do the update new column of original table with the value in temp table